# Feature extraction (mean ,std , contrast, variance,hog ,harrias,entropy,smooth)

Tags: python

I have a data set include 360 images 
I want to calculate some feature about each image like (mean, std, contrast, variance, hog, harris, entropy, smooth)
how I calculate this feature about each image only

Comment: Please include a [mcve] with what you have so far.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the **tour** (https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), "What Are Good Topics" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

This is a very general question so I am going to try to give you a very general solution.

It sounds like what you are trying to do is some type of image process/machine learning.

There are several really well-made libraries and tutorials already out there for Python. My favorite is [OpenCV](https://opencv.org/) since it can run on a RaspberryPi, but [TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/), [Keras](https://keras.io/), [PyTorch](https://pytorch.org/) are all really good options as well. If I recall correctly, Pytorch is actually built specifically for Python.